# How to solve the error for DecimalFormat on a calculator app

Tags: java, android, calculator

I am making a calculator app.

`workingsTV` is the place where calculating is shown.

`resultsTV` is the place showing the result of calculating.

`workings` is doing math by using rhino's library.

I want to add a comma at every three digits on both `workingsTV` and `resultsTV`.

I tried to use it like this for `resultsTV`.

```
 DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###,###.####", new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US));
                result = Double.parseDouble(df.format(result));
```

But then the app was closed when to show `result`

This is the error message

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1,235"

**Here is the top part of the code**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView workingsTV;
    TextView resultsTV;

    String workings = "";
    String CLEAR_INT_TEXT;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initTextView();
    }



    private void initTextView()
    {
        workingsTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.workingsTextView);
        resultsTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultTextView);
    }

    private void setWorkings(String givenValue)
    {
        workings = workings + givenValue;
        workingsTV.setText(workings);

    }


    public void equalsOnClick(View view)
    {
        Double result = null;
        ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("rhino");

        try {
            result = (Double) engine.eval(workings);
            if (result != null)
            {

                DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###,###.####", new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US));
                result = Double.parseDouble(df.format(result));


                int intVal = (int) result.doubleValue();
                if (result == intVal)
                {//Check if it's value is equal to its integer part
                    resultsTV.setText(String.valueOf(intVal));
                }
                else
                {
                    resultsTV.setText(String.valueOf(result));
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using that function to convert double to formatted string

```
public String formatDouble(double value, int digits) {
    DecimalFormatSymbols decimalFormatSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    decimalFormatSymbols.setGroupingSeparator(',');
    decimalFormatSymbols.setDecimalSeparator('.');
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00", decimalFormatSymbols);
    decimalFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(digits);
    decimalFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(digits);
    return decimalFormat.format(value);
}
```

In your code, you already have an result value here `result = (Double) engine.eval(workings);`. Why do you want get it second time? In addition, using formatted string, who may contains illegal character for double (comma char).

Just remove that two lines

```
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###,###.####", new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US));
            result = Double.parseDouble(df.format(result));
```

And format result value when you'll set it to TextView, example with my function:

```
resultsTV.setText(formatDouble(result, 4));
```

At the end of equalsOnClick() method, you should set `result` or `intVal`  to the `workings` variable to make it ready for next operations.

```
workings = String.valueOf(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for your example. It works when I put between if (result == intVal)
                {                    resultsTV.setText(formatDouble(result, 0));
                }

Comment: But then how can I make it if the number is 1234.1+1 for `else`?. Also, how can I make it possible for `workingsTV`? Sorry that I am a beginner so it's difficult to code well.

Comment: @WoojuSpace I think you should at the end `equalsOnClick()` method set result as workings. Look my edit.

Comment: I am reading what you write again and again. But it's so hard to understand. 
Formatted string cannot be used for Double? So I have to set it up again?

Comment: If I use `resultsTV.setText(formatDouble(result, 2));`
It shows different result for Int and Double. 
`1000+1=1,001.00`
`1000+1.1=1001.1`  (At Double, it is not formattted)

Comment: I cannot understand what you said at the last. Sorry... Do you mean set for Double formatted? Make another method?

Comment: @WoojuSpace I mean already formatted value. `1,001.00` is not parsable, so `Double.parseDouble("1,001.00")` will return `NumberFormatException`. I don't know, what you pass to `setWorkings()` method, but remember, you cannot do `1,001.00 + 1.1`, because this will cause error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

Locale locale = new Locale("en", "US");
NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
System.out.println(fmt.format(1235.00));
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. Where do I put the code of Locale?